# how to add 1 to a column in dataframe range

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i want a range of values from two columns **From** and **To** since the number in To column should be included in range of values so i'm adding 1 to that as shown in below

```
df.apply(lambda x : range(x['From'],x['To']+1),1)
df.apply(lambda x : ','.join(map(str, range(x['From'],x['To']))),1)
```

i need output some thing like this

if from value starts from 5 and To value ends with 11

myoutput should be like this

```
5,6,7,8,9,10,11
```

i'm getting till 10 only even i have added +1 to range of end value

```
df:
----
From    To
15887   16251
15888   16252
15889   16253
15890   16254
```

and range should be written in new column

Comment: you haven't shown what `df` is. Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: a common gotcha for people new to pandas is that `df.apply()` by default applies to `axis=0`, which means that your lambda function sees one column at a time. To apply to rows, use `df.apply(..., axis=1)`.

Comment: @PierreD i mentioned axis as 1  after range function. i just didn't gave name

Comment: fair enough, but please provide a MRE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'From':[15887,15888,15889,15890],'To':[16251,16252,16253,16254]})
df['Range']=[list(range(i,k+1)) for i,k in zip(df['From'],df['To'])]
```